# Different Filters for Different Columns

Tags: sql-server

I am relatively new to SQL and I have the following question. I have the following code:

```
Select * from table1 

LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name and table1.id = table2.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM table2 GROUP BY id) newtable ON table1.id = newtable.id
```

As both left joins uses data from the same table, is it possible to combine the two joins into one? How would the filters work in this case?

Comment: What does your data look like? What are you trying to get for results? Show some examples and you will get better responses.

Comment: From what you posted I would simply remove the second join. It is completely redundant as the only column is id which is the exact same join predicate as table2. What is the point of the second join here? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal just to join `table2` based on distinct values, then you can use `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`:

```
Select 
*
from table1  t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name and t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1 id in (SELECT s2.id FROM table2 s2 GROUP BY s2.id)
```